# How do I know which classes have been compiled

Tags: java

I have a file `A.java` and a classpath to find other necessary classes.

So, I compile with

```
javac -cp myclasspath A.java
```

`javac` compiles `A.java` and whatever other files it needs from the classpath.

How can I know which exact files from the classpath have been compiled, besides `A.java`?

Comment: In classpath you only have compiled classes. so there are no files compiled by javac.

Comment: @Jens this is not true

Comment: From [javac Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html): `-cp path or -classpath path` "Specifies where to find user class files, and (optionally) annotation processors and source files." ... "If the `-sourcepath` option is not specified, then the user class path is also searched for source files."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run javac with the [-verbose option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), and parse the results.

> **-verbose**
>       Verbose output. This includes information about each class loaded and each source file compiled.

Answer (score 0):

After you've cleaned your buildspace from class files, build and run a search command on your classpath, like

**Code :**

```
find CLASSPATH -name "*\.class"
```

if you are on a `unixolike` os.

Comment: Sure, but is there any other way?

Comment: perhaps compiling with debug information `javac -g ...` helps and have a look afterwards with `javap -l ...` searching for signatures with some classpath prefix.
another option would be to grep for constructor like commands in your source, but that would probably let you miss some calls/classes.